# Como criar eventos em uma estrutura de repetição for?

Tags: c#, webforms, for, click, void

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um programa (Sou iniciante) em C#.
A parte que eu queria melhorar, é a seguinte: Eu estou querendo criar diferentes eventos em uma estrutura for.
Por exemplo:

```
public frmSelecaoDeCartas()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Declara arrays contendo os Botões
    Button[] btn = { button2, button3, button4 };

    // Inicia uma estrutura de repetição para gerar os eventos
    for (int i = 0; i < btn.Length; i++)
    {
        // Cria o evento do Button de índice I com o nome de btnNum (Num = 0 a 4)
        btn[i].Click += btnNum_Click;

        // Evento com o código (Problema nessa parte, quero trocar a palavra Num por
        // números de acordo com a mudança da índice i (i++)
        void btnNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(CartasInformacao[i], "Informações",
                             MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Ficaria assim:

```
btn[i].Click += btnNum_Click;

void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
// E assim vai...
```

Isso é possível? Se sim, me ajuda? Grato!

Comment: Ao invés de postar um print do seu código, poste o código por completo, desta forma fica melhor para analisar ele.

Comment: Mas é esse o código, o resto é apenas lógica e códigos do programa em si... Nada haver com o código que eu printei, e o que eu printei mostra toda a minha dúvida. Mas lá vai um print maior: http://prntscr.com/gtt3as

Comment: @LucasNaja mas colocar o trecho de codigo aqui facilita nos a ajudarmos você, até facilita copiar e colar para textar

Comment: Quando você adiciona a um so botão funciona?

Comment: Ahh sim, obrigado pela dica. Vai o código: https://pastebin.com/v382kTPF

Atualmente há 3 botões, quando eu executo o código, os três ficam com o mesmo código, pois estão no mesmo evento (btn_Click)
Por exemplo, eu clico no botão 2 e aparece a mesma mensagem clicando no botão 3
Eu queria criar um evento para cada botão usando o for, e não o mesmo evento para cada botão

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que ao criar um delegate a variável capturada `i` é a variável de controle do `for`, que será incrementada a cada iteração. Entretanto, o mesmo `i` será referenciado por todos os eventos... ou seja, a cada incremento do `for` todas as referências vão ver `i` incrementando.

Se você fizer uma cópia da variável, para outra variável, antes de criar o delegate, o mesmo será criado com uma referência para a variável copiada. A declaração da variável tem que estar dentro do `for` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
// Inicia uma estrutura de repetição para gerar os eventos
for (int i = 0; i < btn.Length; i++)
{
    var copia_de_i = i;

    // Cria o evento do Button de índice I com o nome de btnNum (Num = 0 a 4)
    btn[i].Click += btnNum_Click;

    // Evento com o código (Problema nessa parte, quero trocar a palavra Num por
    // números de acordo com a mudança da índice i (i++)
    void btnNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(CartasInformacao[copia_de_i], "Informações", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Problema resolvido, estou muito grato com as respostas rápidas e eficientes! Todos ajudaram bastante :)
Caraca, olha os deuses mano! Obrigado novamente, vocês são fodas! <3

Comment: @LucasNaja: se achar devido, aceite essa resposta. Isso tem 2 objetivos, recompensar a mim, e também marcar a questão como estando respondida. De nada amigo!!! E valeu pelas palavras. =D

Comment: Malditas capturas de contexto...

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim! Considerando o código que já tem pronto eu mudaria apenas uma coisa: acrescentaria `new` antes de associar o evento.

```
btn[i].Click += new btnNum_Click;
```

Comment: Olá, esse exemplo me parece ser correto! Mas, quando eu faço isso, aparece o seguinte: http://prntscr.com/gtt8i0
Aí eu modifico para isso: http://prntscr.com/gtt8mr

Mas aí ao clicar nos botões, os 3 ainda ficam com o mesmo código..
Estou fazendo errado o código btn[i].Click += new btnNum_Click;? Falta algo?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Quando você associa o mesmo evento aos botões, ao clicá-lo o mesmo evento será disparado. O que você pode fazer é criar fluxos diferentes dentro do evento conforme o botão que foi clicado:       

          switch ((sender as Button).Name)
                {
                case "button1":
                    //actions
                    break;
                case "button2":
                    //actions
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
               }